# Can I batch sends in a Solana transaction?

Tags: send-transaction, transaction

currently I am trying to get an example transaction where

(1) Multiple address(wallets) sends to ONE address(wallet)

(2) Multiple address(wallets) sends to multiple address(wallets)

in one signature and transaction, is it possible? if so can someone link me a example transaction?

For example in this case

https://solscan.io/tx/4sXvsjGoURBxmbtAnvFSQE6AXWh98eReqFZVQb7nisGCTzJK2P7xjDDPHhQCdDPuoiJWqCjmUTDb6F5KwsM3vhcP

This case is where One address(wallet) sends to multiple address(wallet) in one signature/transaction

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found how to do (2) (Multiple address(wallets) sends to multiple address(wallets))? I've been trying to do that for about a week now in python, and still can't get it to work.

Comment: No, I think there aggregators out there that do this.

Answer (score 2):

> in one signature and transaction, is it possible?

Yes, all of that is possible. But the question is not ideally suited to describe what is happening on the blockchain.

In Solana, transactions are one or more instructions that are grouped together and signed by the sender(signed with the private key of the wallet/account).

In your link, you have a transaction that is composed of several instructions. You can see this in the `Instruction Details` section, where you have 16 instructions in total.

So while your transaction is indeed a situation where *One address(wallet) sends to multiple address(wallet) in one signature/transaction*, it is formed by a bunch of smaller instructions that each actually only contain a transfer from one account(address/wallet) to another. A transaction can contain any number of instructions, that each does it's own thing.

So if we want to have multiple accounts(addresses/wallets if you wish) to make transfers to a single account, let's say accounts A, B, C make transfers to account D, we can create a transaction that will contain instructions where each instruction individually is a single transfer from a different account to account D:

- instruction 1: `A transfer to D`
- instruction 2: `B transfer to D`
- instruction 3: `C transfer to D`

Grouped together in a transaction this would result in accounts A, B, C making a transfer to a single account, D.

But also, a single instruction can contain several transfers from several accounts to a single account or vice-versa, you can have a program that does this, Solana allows for such a situation.

Another aspect, in your example the transfer that is happening is a SPL transfer, which is a token transfer, another type of transfer possible is a SOL transfer, which superficially might seem roughly similar, underneath, it's a completely different thing.

All in all, I am trying to say that while what you are asking is possible, there are a number of ways to do this and even if we get an example of what you're looking for, I am not sure what you can get from that.

Can you offer maybe more information of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Is it possible you can give me one signature or transaction where

(1) Multiple address(wallets) sends to ONE address(wallet)

(2) Multiple address(wallets) sends to multiple address(wallets)

Like Ethereum indexed data I can get transaction (from address to address value(amount transffered) but for solana i have to calculate balance changes my self, for example in the data if one sends to multiple address I have to calculate the balance myself, so i am trying to find a transaction (1) and (2) in solscan for SPL transfer